# R - getting no data when scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am having the same problem as listed here; however, I am using R rather than python: [Getting no data when scraping a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514076/getting-no-data-when-scraping-a-table)

I am trying to scrape historical bitcoin data from https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/

Here is the code in which I am running. url_tables results in a list of 0.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url<-'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/'

#extract html

url_html<-read_html(url)

#table extraction

url_tables<- url_html %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a bit of a noob.

Comment: The table is part of javascript dinamically generated content, thus `rvest` will porbably not be enough to render it properly. One alternative is to use Selenium.

Comment: An [example of using RSelenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66217591/13513328)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using Selenium to control a  Firefox browser.
Note that you must have Selenium installed and added to your operating system's PATH in order for this to work properly. See here for details: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/driver_requirements/

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
    
url<-'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/'

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port=4545L, verbose=TRUE) #If port 4525 does not work, simply change it to 4546, 4547...
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate(url = url) #This should open a Firefox instance in a new window.
    
#capture html
obj_html<-remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html(encoding = "UTF-8")

#table extraction
table <- obj_html %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//div/table") %>% html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame() %>% as_tibble()


# A tibble: 58 x 7
   Date     Open.   High    Low     Close.. Volume    Market.Cap 
   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>      
 1 Mar 06,~ $48,89~ $49,14~ $47,25~ $48,91~ $34,363,~ $912,054,1~
 2 Mar 05,~ $48,52~ $49,39~ $46,54~ $48,92~ $48,625,~ $912,285,0~
 3 Mar 04,~ $50,52~ $51,73~ $47,65~ $48,56~ $52,343,~ $905,414,1~
 4 Mar 03,~ $48,41~ $52,53~ $48,27~ $50,53~ $53,220,~ $942,236,5~
 5 Mar 02,~ $49,61~ $50,12~ $47,22~ $48,37~ $47,530,~ $901,933,6~
 6 Mar 01,~ $45,15~ $49,78~ $45,11~ $49,63~ $53,891,~ $925,235,5~
 7 Feb 28,~ $46,19~ $46,71~ $43,24~ $45,13~ $53,443,~ $841,428,9~
 8 Feb 27,~ $46,34~ $48,25~ $45,26~ $46,18~ $45,910,~ $860,978,1~
 9 Feb 26,~ $47,18~ $48,37~ $44,45~ $46,33~ $350,967~ $863,752,2~
10 Feb 25,~ $49,70~ $51,94~ $47,09~ $47,09~ $54,506,~ $877,766,1~
# ... with 48 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely looks like you have what I want! I am just getting this error message:Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
  Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
   Detail: A new session could not be created.
  Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.

Comment: It is probably telling you that the port 4545 is in use.
Try changing it to something else, like 4546 or 4550. See my note in the code.
ex: `rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port=4546L, verbose=TRUE)`

Comment: No, i had that error a few times so changed the port until i got this error instead! I'll have another play after work. Thanks!